# MySQL: Multi-column join on several tables

Tags: sql, mysql, join, unions

I have several tables that I am joining that I need to add another table to and I can't seem to get the right query. Here is what I have now -

Table 1
carid, catid, makeid, modelid, caryear

Table 2
makeid, makename

Table 3
modelid, modelname

Table 4
catid, catname

The query I am using to join these is:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
  JOIN table2 b on a.makeid=b.makeid
  JOIN table3 c on a.modelid=c.modelid
  JOIN table4 d on a.catid=d.catid
  WHERE a.carid = $carid;
```

Now I need to add a 5th table that I am getting from a 3rd party that I am having a hard time adding to my existing query. The new table has these fields -

Table 5
id, year, make, model, citympg, hwympg

I need the citympg and hwympg based on caryear from table 1, makename from table 2, and modelname from table 3. I know I can do a second query with those values, but I would prefer to do a single query and have all of the data in a single row. Can this be done in a single query? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's possible to have more than condition in a join.
does this work?

```
SELECT a.*, e.citympg, e.hwympg
FROM table1 a
  JOIN table2 b on a.makeid=b.makeid
  JOIN table3 c on a.modelid=c.modelid
  JOIN table4 d on a.catid=d.catid
  Join table5 e on b.makename = e.make
                and c.modelname = e.model
                and a.caryear = e.year
  WHERE a.carid = $carid;
```

...though your question is not clear. Did you *only* want to join table5 to the others, or was there something else you wanted to do with table5?

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Whoops, think it's fixed now.

Comment: I think Frustrated meant `on a.caryear = e.year` instead of `on a.citympg = e.citympg and a.hwympg = e.hwympg`

Comment: @ypercube: er, yeah, ... that's what I meant!

Comment: This works, but now I have a new problem. The new table has additional criteria that we don't use so the query returns several rows. Ideally I would like to get a single row with the average citympg and hwympg.

Comment: @Brent Friar: Not sure what's happening without some sample data; if you are getting duplicate rows, have you tried `select distinct`?

Comment: On the mpgs table, year/make/model are not unique, there is a 4th criteria (engine size) so this query returns one row per engine size. I would also not return any rows if there was no match on that table. I asked a follow up questions and got the correct answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952037/mysql-multi-column-join-on-several-tables-part-ii

Answer (score 1):

Without indexes, It won't be efficient, but you can do

```
LEFT JOIN table5 ON (table2.make = table5.make AND table3.model = table5.model AND table1.caryear = table5.caryear)
```

This also assumes the make and models and years strings match exactly.

Comment: Agree, and I think you may have troubles if the name is like "Escort" in one, "escort" in another and "Escort " (space at end) in a third. You may want to trim whitespace and convert to upper or lower case for the comparison.

Comment: The makes and models are all presented as drop down selections and those are normalized before they are inserted in to the table, so that will help minimize the problems with matching.